Why does Laminas API throw a CORS error when using POST to persist a collection?
Setup:
I am using Laminas API Tools and Angular 17 to create a Webapp. One of my resources is the Article resource. I want to enable users to create either a single new Article via a provided form, or a collection of Articles via importing a CSV file.
Since I need to enable the user to alter the provided data in their CSV files anyways, I am parsing the data in Angular 17 on the client and create an Article array from the parsed and altered data.
I then POST the Article or the Article array to my /articles endpoint, where I verify that the posted data is either an Article or an array of Articles, and then create one or multiple entities accordingly.
Problem:
Creating a single Article works fine and returns Status Code 201. Creating multiple Articles at once not. It Returns **Status Code 200 Cross-Origin Request blocked, BUT after manually reloading the collection, all Articles have been created ... twice!
Questions:
Why do the objects get persisted, but the endpoint return the cross-origin error only when creating multiple entities? Why do they get persisted twice?

ArticleMapper:
class ArticleMapper extends EntityMapper {

  public function create($data, $identity) {

    if ($data instanceof Traversable) {
      $data = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($data);
    }

    if (is_object($data)) {
      $data = (array) $data;
    }
    if (!is_array($data)) {
      throw new InvalidArgumentException(
        sprintf(
          'Invalid data provided to %s; must be an array or Traversable',
          __METHOD__
        )
      );
    }

    $user = $this->getUserByIdentity($identity);
    $account = $user->getAccount();
    // Very basic verification that the data has one of the required fields, if so create an article
    if (array_key_exists('name', $data)) {
      $article = $this->hydrator->hydrate($data, new Article());
      $article->setAccount($account);
      $this->entityManager->persist($article);
      // this works and returns 201
    } else {
      // else it should be a collection
      forEach ($data as $articleData) {
        if (array_key_exists('name', $articleData)) {
          $article = $this->hydrator->hydrate($articleData, new Article());
          $article->setAccount($account);
          $this->entityManager->persist($article);
        }
      }
      // this works partially, it creates all elements twice and returns 200 cross-origin: request blocked
    }
    $this->entityManager->flush();
  }
}

PS: I dont suspect my CORS Setup to be the culprit here, I am using LmcCors with this Setup and have no issues with any request so far:
[...]
    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:4200', 'https://localhost:4200'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'CONNECT', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS',   'TRACE'],
    'allowed_headers' => ['Authorization', 'Content-Type', 'Accept']

[EDIT]:
It was relatively simple in the end. While creating Articles from the CSV file, there was no ['id'] field present in the data. This led to an error when setting the id field in the hydrator and accessing the id. What made this really frustrating though was the fact that the error only was visible after trying to only persist the first article from the array, then the response made that error visible.
One question remains though, why were the entities created twice when the error occured?
